# move_arm_joint_goal

Tags: ros, pr2-simulator, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to perform the move_arm tutorials for the pr2. Once I run ./bin/move_arm_joint_goal in the 'simple_armstack_goals' package I am getting the following error:

[ERROR] [1316613106.599530291]: Client [/move_right_arm] wants topic /move_right_arm/goal to have datatype/md5sum [arm_navigation_msgs/MoveArmActionGoal/d560cc046d6b5e8bf3f70a960054d6c6], but our version has [move_arm_msgs/MoveArmActionGoal/9b271f91d996a9442a767677d36e2eb3]. Dropping connection.

Do you have any idea what causes this error?

I using ROS Electric on Ubuntu 11.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11272/move_arm_joint_goal/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-09-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on 2011-09-21**:
The error did somehow not occur: [ERROR] [1316612972.596361511, 2.494000000]: Client [/move_right_arm] wants topic /move_right_arm/goal to have datatype/md5sum [arm_navigation_msgs/MoveArmActionGoal/d560cc046d6b5e8bf3f70a960054d6c6], but our version has [move_arm_msgs/MoveArmActionGoal/9b271f91d996a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check that both the client (your program) and the robot are running the same version of ROS. If you switched from diamondback to electric many packages should at least be recompiled.

Also be sure that you are sourcing the right setup.bash file (usually /opt/ros/electric) in your .bashrc.

Electric has a diferent structure for the arm_navigation, so probably this is the cause of your error.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on 2011-09-25**:
You're both right, after re-compiling all involved packages it worked. I forgot one package previously. Thanks or your help!

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-09-22**:
Lorenzo is right, the error means that the two nodes communicating over the topic were compiled using two different versions of the MoveArmActionGoal message. Run `env | grep ROS`, check ROS_ROOT and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and run rosmake on all involved packages.

**Comment by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on 2011-09-21**:
I am using electric and have /opt/ros/electric in my .bashrc. So do you mean that the ompl_ros_interface tutorials do not work in electric anymore? I recompiled the packages that are needed for the ompl_ros_interface tutorials but the error still remains there.